# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format [swift 3]

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, nsdictionary

I've json data that have json string(value) that that look like this

```
{
     "Label" : "NY Home1",
     "Value" : "{\"state\":\"NY\",\"city\":\"NY\",\"postalCode\":\"22002\",\"value\":\"Fifth Avenue1\nNY NY 22002\nUSA\",\"iosIdentifier\":\"71395A78-604F-47BE-BC3C-7F932263D397\",\"street\":\"Fifth Avenue1\",\"country\":\"USA\"}",
}
```

I take the jsonString using swiftyjson

```
let value = sub["Value"].string ?? ""
```

After that I convert this jsonString to Dictionary with this below code but it always show this error message `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format`

```
if let data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            let a = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            print("check \(a)")
        } catch {
            print("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

I think this happen because "\n", how to convert jsonstring to dictionary that have "\n" ?

Comment: @EricAya is right. And just a small suggestion: write value of "Value" into dictionary instead of manually typing a string.

Comment: My previous comment was incomplete. The trailing comma is definitely an issue, sure - but the non-escaped linefeeds are also an issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, problem occurred because of "\n". I tried your code without "\n" and it's work perfectly.

I replaced "\n" by "\\n", and iOS seems to convert the string to dictionary :

```
let value =  "{\"state\":\"NY\",\"city\":\"NY\",\"postalCode\":\"22002\",\"value\":\"Fifth Avenue1\nNY NY 22002\nUSA\",\"iosIdentifier\":\"71395A78-604F-47BE-BC3C-7F932263D397\",\"street\":\"Fifth Avenue1\",\"country\":\"USA\"}"

if let data = value.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\\n").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    do {
       let a = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: Any]
       NSLog("check \(a)")
    } catch {
       NSLog("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I obtained this in my log :

```
check Optional(["value": Fifth Avenue1
NY NY 22002
USA, "country": USA, "city": NY, "iosIdentifier": 71395A78-604F-47BE-BC3C-7F932263D397, "street": Fifth Avenue1, "postalCode": 22002, "state": NY])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a key type issue. In my model one key type(instead of int I used string) was wrong. Please check every key in your model class.